# How to install chrome os flow in virtual box

Tags: google-chrome-os

I tried installing chrome os flow which I got from here: http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/
Into the virtual box. 
First, I extracted the tar.gz file and added an existing hard disk to the virtual box and selected the extracted file.
I chose ubuntu linux in the OS selection. And I'm using w7 as the main OS. Do you know of any guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [How to run Chrome OS in VirtualBox](http://chromeos-blog.com/tutorial-chrome-os-virtualbox/).

Comment: You can (also) checkout my 5min video tutorial - http://greenido.wordpress.com/chrome/